# Linking Boost gives me error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

When trying to compile my solution with VS2010 I'm getting a compiler error:
"error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_unit_test_framework-vc100-mt-gd-1_45.lib'"
I've tried to look for this file on hard drive but with no luck.
Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: The obvious answer is get the file and provide path to this file in vs but as I've mentioned before I do not have this file on my hard drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to take precompiled Boost libraries for your system, e.g. from [boostpro.com](http://www.boostpro.com/download/) or build Boost yourself. Then add a path to Boost .lib's to your Linker paths

Comment: Usually binaries at boostpro are very late. Last time I checked (3 weeks ago) the 1.45 were not available. You definitely should compile them yourself. It is very easy, and not very long.

Answer (score 2):

Some Boost libraries require building. As robin hood's answer notes, you can download an install with the binaries included, or you can build them yourself (which is slightly fiddly). See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/windows.html for an extensive discussion.